# How to rename all files in a directory and subdirectories?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to access all files in a directory and it's subdirectories; and I'm trying to implement this code for it to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
NEWNAME="newFile"
echo "- - - - - - - - - - - "
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
for f in *.* *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
FILES=$(find ./ -type f)

for f in $FILES; do
    
    path=$(dirname "${f}")
    extension="${f##*.}"
    echo $extension;
    mv "$f" "${f/$f/${$path/$NEWNAME.$extension}}"
done
```

But my lack of knowledge in bash results in this error:

```
mv: rename * * to *_*: No such file or directory
mv: rename very_important_folder to very_important_folder/very_important_folder: Invalid argument
//very_important_folder/bob
./app.sh: line 13: ${$path/$NEWNAME.$extension}: bad substitution
```

This my folder setup:

```
-very important folder:
  -|filewithoutspaces.py
  -|anothersubfolder:
    --|file with spaces.txt
-app.sh
```

And so, I'm trying to change all the files in the directories 1 name: newname, but leaving the extension as it was. I encountered problems changing files with spaces in their names, and I'm not really familiar with bash.
It does change the files not in folders, but it doesn't work for the ones in subdirectories.
I'm using MacBook Air (M1, 2020) macOS 12.3 Monterey.

Comment: These two lines of code `for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done` and `for f in *.* *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done` can be reduced to a single line, as in: `for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done`.

Comment: There are many problems with the code.  If you can explain *exactly* what you are trying to do then somebody may be able to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to change all the names of all the files in the specific folder to be the same name.
But, due to my lack of knowledge in bash, I've encountered countless problems.

Comment: @ItamarCohen, if you do that then you'll end up with just one file in the folder and all but one of the original files will have been deleted.  Is that *really* what you want?  If not, try to provide a concrete example.  For instance, if you start with a folder containing files `a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `c.txt` what do you want to end up with?  Also the first part of your code seems to be trying to rename files to replace spaces with underscores.  Is that a separate activity or is it related to the rest of the code in some way?

Comment: What I did, for just the files in the directory itself is changing the filename but leaving the extension as it was. Im just asking how to do it, because I don't really care about them all having the same name. this is the purpose.

Comment: @ItamarCohen, sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do.  It would help if you could provide a concrete example: directories and files before and after running the program.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? `to access all files` in what way you want to "access" them? You could consider writing your application to properly handle spaces in paths, instead of renaming all files.

Comment: Try to decompose your complex problem into several single questions. Post as many questions as single problems, please. SO is working in that way.

Comment: before even trying to write bash scripts, read how to handle file names correctly https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html#wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you really wanna do but the following construct can surely help you:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar

for path in ./**
do
    [[ -d "$path" ]] && continue

    [[ $path =~ ^(.*/)([^/]+)(\.[^/]*)$|^(.*/)(.+)$ ]]

    dirpath="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    filename="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
    extension="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

    echo mv "$path" "$dirpath${filename// /_}$extension"
done
```

###### notes:

- `shopt -s globstar` allows the glob `**` to match any path length.
- `./**` is for making sure that there is at least one `/` in the resulting paths. It simplifies greatly the splitting of a path into its different components.
- `[[ -d "$path" ]] && continue` means to skip paths that are directories.
- `[[ $path =~ ... ]]` is a bash way of using a regex for splitting the path into `dirname` `filename` and `extension`.
- `echo ...` Now that you have the different components of the filepath at hand, you can do whatever you want.

---

###### Update

As a workaround for older bash you can define a function and call it in `find`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    local path dirpath filename extension
    for path
    do
        [[ $path =~ ^(.*/)([^/]+)(\.[^/]*)$|^(.*/)(.+)$ ]]

        dirpath="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
        filename="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
        extension="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

        echo mv "$path" "$dirpath${filename// /_}$extension"
    done
}
export -f doit

find . -type f -exec bash -c 'doit "$0" "$@"' {} +
```

Just be aware that if you use an external variable inside the function (like `NEWNAME` in your code), you'll also have to export it: `export NEWNAME="newFile"`.
BTW, it's not safe to capitalise your shell variables.

Comment: Well, it results in `./newcode.sh: line 2: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`

Comment: Oh, so you're running bash-3. `globstar` isn't easily replaceable, you'll have to use a workaround with `find -exec` or `find | xargs`

Comment: How can I install bash 4?

Comment: it seems I also have bash 5, in addition to 3, but it still shows that error... how can I use it?

Comment: One way would be to modify your shebang. For example, if you installed bash-5 using Homebrew then the shebang would need to be something like `#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`